# URL Management in CSS file

Tags: css, url

I have to manage URLs from different domain in my CSS file.
I need help regarding better way to manage it. 
For e.g.
I have 2 classes

```
.class1{
    background: url('http://my.domain1.com/path/to/image') no-repeat;
 }
.class2{
    background: url('http://my.domain2.com/path/to/image') no-repeat;
 }
```

Is there any way like SASS or LESS to manage such URLs in CSS.
For more detail I am using this CSS for Phonegap2.6 to develop an iOS app.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with iOS or phonegap

Comment: Ya so do it the way you are doing, nothing bad in that

Comment: So you are saying that there is no other way than to keep as it is and for next domain name change I have to bulk find and replace every URL?

Comment: I think the next step would be to use LESS/SASS to set a variable for each URL, say a variable for URL of class2 and a variable for class1.  Then just change the URL of the variable to effect the rules further down.  That is getting to the point of micromanagement as far as I'm concerned however.

Comment: Like Michael says you can assign variables in CSS when using SASS or LESS (I like SASS personally), so you could assign variables to the domain URLs and then just use relative paths appended to the end of the appropriate variable.  That way you just need to update the domain variable(s) and compile again if you need to change the domain(s).

Ideally though you would just consolidate the files onto a single server if at all possible...